Name of movie about Irish Village winning the Lottery?
I saw a movie about 10 or so years ago, about a little Irish village on a remote island. It started off simply enough, but after a little while, they found out that one of the village members had died - due to shock from winning the lottery.
Over the course of the movie, they realised that to claim the prize, they had to prove that they were the owner of the winning ticket. The whole plan went awry, due to circumstances requiring the off-sider to impersonate the dead man, rather than the main character as they had intended. He ended up reading personal documents from the toilets to "prove his identity", and was read his own eulogy in place of the dead man's.
Eventually, throughout the course of the movie they also had to enlist the trust of the rest of the community, and decided to share the winnings evenly throughout the village, if they chose to sign up. All save for one woman who demanded more than her fair share, and attempted to threaten turning them in if they didn't comply.
I'm not exactly sure when it was released, but it would have definitely been prior to the early 2000's. What is that name of this movie?

Waking Ned Devine (1998)
You can read the plot here.
It's not the village that wins, it's Ned.  
From IMDB:

When a lottery winner dies of shock, his fellow townsfolk attempt to claim the money.


Waking Ned  has the Irish village, dead man winning lottery and a plot to pretend he is still alive. 
